# Why my rows getting duplicated and showing summing incorrectly?

Tags: sql-server-2016, aggregate

I have these tables:

```
Payments

vendor   | VendorLocation | VendorName   | CheckDate | Amount | TransactionID | InvoiceID
---------------------------------------------------------------------
777      |                | Sony        | 5/1/2020   | 1.50   | 345           | ABC555
777      |                | Sony        | 5/1/2020   | 1.20   | 444           | ABC555
777      |  103           | Sony Music  | 5/1/2020   | 8.50   | 888           | XYZ888
777      |  105           | Sony VR     | 5/1/2020   | 2.50   | 789           | XYZ999
777      |  105           | Sony VR     | 5/1/2020   | 2.50   | 833           | XYZ111
```

```
Vendor Location

vendor   | VendorLocation | LocationType |Address 1   | State | City
---------------------------------------------------------------------
777      |  103           | X            |123 Ave      | CA    | Rivertown
777      |  105           | Z            |666 Ave      | CA    | Northtown
777      |  106           | Z            |888 Ave      | CA    | Southtown
```

```
Vendor Address

vendor   | VendorLocation | Address 1  | State | City
---------------------------------------------------------------------
777      |                | 1 Main St  | CA    | Rivertown
777      |  103           | 123 Ave    | CA    | Rivertown
777      |  105           | 666 Ave    | CA    | Northtown
```

What I want the output to be:

```
Vendor Spending

vendor   | VendorLocation | LocationType  | VendorName | TotalTransactions|TotalSpend| Address 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------
777      |                | Z             | Sony       |  2                | $2.70   | 1 Main St
777      |  105           | Z             | Sony VR    |  2                | $5.00   | 666 Ave
```

However I'm getting below result which are duplicates and incorrect totalSpend amount:

```
Vendor Spending

vendor   | VendorLocation | LocationType  | VendorName | TotalTransactions|TotalSpend| Address 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------
777      |                | Z             | Sony       |  2                | $2.70   | 1 Main St
777      |  105           | Z             | Sony VR    |  2                | $7.70   | 1 Main St


This is query I have:

select distinct
ap.vendor Vendor_ID
,vl.VendorLocation
,vl.LocationType
,ap.VendorName
,count(ap.transactionID) as TotalTransactions
,sum( ap.amount) as TotalSpend
,ad.Address1
from payments ap
join  VendorLocation vl
on ( (vl.vendor=ap.vendor and vl.VendorLocation=ap.VendorLocation)
or (vl.vendor=ap.vendor and vl.VendorLocation='')
or (vl.vendor=ap.vendor and ap.VendorLocation='')
and vl.LocationType in ('Z')
) join VENDORADDRESS ad
on (ad.VENDOR=ap.vendor AND ad.VendorLocation=ap.VendorLocation)
where
vl.LocationType in ('Z') and
ap.CheckDate>='4/1/2022'
group by
vl.vendor
,vl.LOCATION_CODE
,vl.LocationType
,ap.VendorName
,ad.Address1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some fairly denormalized tables. Repeating the same data points across multiple tables (such as `Address 1`) is redundant, inefficient, and most importantly can lead to poor data integrity. I'd recommend fixing your table design.

---

That aside, your query can be simplified like so:

```
;WITH _VendorTransactionTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        vendor, 
        VendorLocation, 
        VendorName,
        COUNT(1) AS TotalTransactions,
        SUM(Amount) AS TotalSpend
    FROM Payments
    WHERE CheckDate >= '4/1/2022'
    GROUP BY vendor, VendorLocation, VendorName
)

SELECT
    VTT.vendor, 
    VTT.VendorLocation,
    VL.LocationType,
    VTT.VendorName,
    VTT.TotalTransactions,
    VTT.TotalSpend,
    VL.[Address 1]
FROM _VendorTransactionTotals AS VTT
INNER JOIN [Vendor Location] AS VL
    ON VTT.vendor = VL.vendor
    AND VTT.VendorLocation = VL.VendorLocation
WHERE VL.LocationType = 'Z'
```

By utilizing a CTE to aggregate your `Payments` table first, this de-dupes it before joining in the `Vendor Location` table. This also makes the query more readable and simplifies the code.

---

Note you should also use standard names for tables and columns that don't have *odd* characters in them such as spaces.

---

By the way, the issue with your original query most likely lies here:

```
or (vl.vendor=ap.vendor and vl.VendorLocation='')
or (vl.vendor=ap.vendor and ap.VendorLocation='')
and
```

This is saying that any row in the `Vendor Location` table with a *blank* `VendorLocation` can join to **all** rows with the same `vendor` in the `Payments` table, and visa-versa, any rows in the `Payments` table with a *blank* `VendorLocation` can join to **all** rows with the same `Vendor` in the `Vendor Location` table.

Also, it's unclear how the `Vendor Address` table relates to the `Vendor Location` table, especially for the blank address. How do you know `1 Main St` relates to `LocationType = 'Z'`? Clarifying that will likely help determine if your goal is possible and how to best achieve it.

Comment: if VendorLocation on Payments is blank then it doesnt need to join with VendorLocation table, it can go straight to Vendor Address and join the row with blank VendorLocation and select Addr1 from it. 

I know the tables are awful but i can't do anything about it unfortunately. But I like your WITH example, I will play around with it and go from there.

Comment: using the WITH I was able to make it output the way I want it. Thank you so much!